# How can I check in the json schema validator that the values of a certain field are included in an array of real values?

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, jsonata

I have many different objects that have their own IDs, I need to check that the **source ** field (which refers to one of the real IDs) was filled in by a person correctly. I don't quite understand how this can be implemented

```
  schema:           
    type: object
    properties:
      source:
        type: string
        pattern: "^(\\([0-9]{3}\\))?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$"
    required:
    - source
    additionalProperties: true
  source: >      #source of validation                               
    (
      $validator := $jsonschema($self.schema); 
      ([([
        components.$spread().( 
          $ID := $keys()[0];
          {                                                                 
            "id": $ID,                                                   =
            "isvalid": $validator($.*)                                   
          }
        )        
      ][isDocHubDomain and isComponent and isvalid != true]).isvalid.{    
        "uid": $.params.missingProperty & "-component-" & %.id,           
        "location": "/architect/components/" & %.id,                      
        "correction": "Fill required field",                       
        "description": message
      }])
    )
```

There is a list of keys that I just have to match the value in the source field to check that it is real.  ($.opportunities.$keys()   its how can i get to keys (id)  # ['sasd','reg','dsfdsf','asdas' and more 50]

Comment: Please don't tag-spam.  The jQuery Validate plugin has nothing to do with your question.  Edited.